# Exception with Simple XML framework deserialization

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization

I'm facing a problem to deserialize an XML file which have successfully been serialized with the [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) framework (simpleframework.org).

There is [an exception](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/core/PersistenceException.html) thrown:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class projet.sarelo.Note
```

This is the call:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
File xmlFile = new File(path);
ContactList contactList = serializer.read(ContactList.class, xmlFile); <== Error
```

My ContactList.java

```
@Root(strict=false, name="ContacList")
public class ContactList {      
    @ElementArray (name = "Contacts")
    Contact [] contact;     
}
```

My Note.java

```
public class Note {
    @Element(required=false)
    private String note;

    public Note(String note) {
        super();
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }
}
```

My Contact.java

```
@Root
public class Contact {
@Attribute(name = "id") 
public String id;       

@Element(name="Nom", required=false)                
String name; 

@ElementArray(name="Phones", required=false)
Phone [] phone; 

@ElementArray(name = "Emails", required=false)
Email [] email; 

@ElementArray(name = "Adresses", required=false)
Adresses [] adresses;

@ElementArray(name = "Notes", required=false)
Note [] note;

public Contact(String id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}   

public String getId(){
    return id;
}
}
```

And this is the XML file I'm trying to deserialize.

```xml
<ContactList>
<Contacts length="5">
  <contact id="1">
     <Adresses length="0"/>
     <Emails length="0"/>
     <Notes length="1">
        <note>
           <note>dgfdg</note>
        </note>
     </Notes>
  </contact>
  <contact id="2">
     <Adresses length="1">
        <adresses>
           <city>Paris </city>
           <postcode>751234 </postcode>
           <state>France</state>
           <street>Pignon</street>
        </adresses>
     </Adresses>
     <Emails length="1">
        <email type="home">
           <home>nicolas.sarkozy@elysee.fr</home>
        </email>
     </Emails>
     <Nom>Nicolas  Sarkozy </Nom>
     <Notes length="1">
        <note>
           <note>Je suis le president de toute la france. Le grand president</note>
        </note>
     </Notes>
     <Phones length="2">
        <phone>
           <home>+33 1234</home>
        </phone>
        <phone>
           <mobile>+33 0612</mobile>
        </phone>
     </Phones>
  </contact>
    ...
</Contacts>
</ContactList>
```

Comment: FYI, very similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5894320/642706) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16135304/642706)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## No-Arg Constructor

I don't know this particular XML framework, but, usually you need a constructor that takes no parameters/arguments for each class that you wish to be deserialized. Such constructors are known as a "no-arg", "0-argument", or (formally) [nullary constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullary_constructor).

Otherwise, the framework cannot instantiate the class.

Comment: Thanks @Timores. I generated empty constructors for each class and it's now working.

Comment: Thanks @Timores! I had an issue with one of my data object classes (the root class to be exact). The constructor it had was set to private, because I was using a static method "loadFromXml" in the same class to instantiate an object. Long story short: you **need** either a public No-Arg constructor or a public annotated constructor (see Bourque's direct comment to the question) in order to have the program deserialize the XML source properly.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am getting this Error when running proguard on my app. Could you take a look at the [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407587/1889768).

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to delete things from constructor. You can just add something like this:

```
public Contact(@Element (name = "id") String id, @Element (name = "name") String name) {
...
```

It was working for me :)

Comment: Just a note here, after the annotation you must also add the `(name= "")` matching the name of the variable you deserialized.

Comment: This is the better answer IMHO. I overlooked this in the Simple-Framework documentation, but it is what the tutorials tell you to do. http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#immutable  See Constructor Injection.

Comment: This helped me understand my problem. But I am getting this exception for no/default constructor. However adding all elements to the constructor does seem to solve the issue. However I have a code amount of huge to go through if I want to get it done. Is there a simpler solution for that?

Answer (score -3):

I think it is better to use SAX for parsing an XML this is an example of parsing:

You need to create a class parser like this:

```
 { public class DataXMLReader  extends DefaultHandler {



    public DataXMLReader() {


    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName,Attributes atts) 
    {
                if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("window"))
                {
                    atts.getValue("type_id") // to get proprietis 
                }
                else if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("component"))
                {  

                }


    }



    public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)

            throws SAXException {

         if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("component"))
        { 
             if(Integer.parseInt(typeid)<=6)
                idParent.remove(idParent.size()-1);

        }       
            }

       @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.startDocument();

            Log.e("StartDoc","Reading XML");
        }
            public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myBdd.close(); 
                Log.e("EndtDoc","End XML");

                    }

}
}
```

and this is an example to call XML from URL:

```
String url="http://vxbfdhbf.xml";
        try {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)sourceUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.connect();



            DataXMLReader myXMLHandler = new DataXMLReader(this,"1");
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

            xr.parse(new InputSource(connection.getInputStream()));
            connection.disconnect();






        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("saxERR",""+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Yaz but problem is now solved :)
I haven't tried SAX yet but take a brief look at [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net) and I'm sure you wont regret. It's quiet simple.

Comment: @MohamedYaz As San Francesco said, [SimpleFramework.org](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) really is simple for this kind of work, serializing objects to XML. One or two lines of code can do all that SAX work you show.

Comment: Can you just point major part of the code and explain needed to resolve the issue?