# Constructor not matched for class

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to deserialize an xml file, But I am having errors on deserializing it using the code below:

```
try {
    Strategy strategy = new CycleStrategy("id", "ref");
    Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
    File source = new File("ActionToLettersAndBorrowers.xml");
    ProcessEngineObject op = serializer.read(ProcessEngineObject.class, source);

    System.out.println(op.getName());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am i missing something out? I got the idea from simplexml website.

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting?

Comment: Please, make sure that the class you are trying to deserialize has a default public constructor.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407587/335858). Unfortunately, the other question has no answer, only a work-around.

Comment: @LaurentDeCant i have a constructor.
    public Email(String to, String from, String subject, String body) {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.body = body;
    }

Comment: @GBlodgett org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class nhmfc.filenet.xml.Email

Comment: I tried to convert the constructor into a public void method, and it works. I don't know if simplexml cannot read constructors?

Comment: SimpleXml like most of XML framework needs a no-arg constructor for deserialization. That was your error, and by removing your constructor, the default one was applied. Possible duplicate of [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471452/4629012)

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you just need to predefine your properties. Example:

```
@Root(name = "Response")
data class LinkResponse @JvmOverloads constructor(
@field:Element(name = "Field1")
var bucket: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field2")
var key: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field3")
var etag: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field4")
var location: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two constructors, like:

```
class Strategy {
...
    Strategy(){...}
    Strategy(String id, String ref){...}
}
```

Another approach could be defining a no-arg constructor and then set the properties you need.