# How to parse xml having same name but different data

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2, simple-framework

I have to parse xml response like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>RESULT_CODE</name>
                        <value>
                            <array>
                                <data>
                                    <value>SUCCESS</value>
                                </data>
                            </array>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>MEMBER_KEY</name>
                        <value>de1cc72569709126282f76cca4c1111a3813c131</value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>TEMP_HOLD_TIME</name>
                        <value>12</value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

In my Android project, I use `compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta4')` and make model like this

```
    public class Response {

    @Element
    public Params params;

    public static class Params {
        @Element
        public Param param;
    }

    public static class Param {
        @Element
        public Value value;
    }

    public static class Value {
        @Element
        public Struct struct;
    }

    public static class Struct {
        @Element
        public Member member;

        @ElementList(required = false, inline = true)
        public List<Member1>  members;
    }

    public static class Member {
        @Element
        public String name;

        @Element
        public Value1 value;
    }

    public static class Value1 {
        @Element
        public Array array;
    }

    public static class Array {
        @Element
        public Data data;
    }

    public static class Data {
        @Element
        public String value;
    }

    public static class Member1 {
        @Element
        public String name;

        @Element
        public String value;
    }

}
```

My request is success but when parsing data, I got the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'member' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'member' public Response$Member Response$Struct.member at line 2
```

I'm not sure about Struct class. How to make it properly?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999265/parsing-xml-feed-die-with-element-is-already-used